# How do I add a lot of data to Sequelize model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have many .txt files where each line has some data that I want to add to a model, so that it can be ready for querying. The problem is that none of the "insert" queries are being executed, probably due to the asynchronicity of the library.

Here's what I have:

```
// Connect to DB
// Set up Model
// Model.sync()

// first for loop (for each .txt)
// second for loop (nested) (for each line in the .txt)
// in second for loop: Model.create(data);
```

What do I do to insure that each data object is successfully added to the database?

Here's the code:

```
var Location = sequelize.define('Location', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  country: Sequelize.STRING,
  lat: Sequelize.STRING,
  long: Sequelize.STRING
});
Location.sync().success(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < txts.length; i++){
    var txt = txts[i],
      country = txt.substr(0, txt.indexOf('.')),
      data = fs.readFileSync(dir +"/" + txt, 'utf-8'),
      locations = data.split('\n');

    for (var j =1; j < locations.length; j++){
      var loc = locations[j],
        chunks = _.without(loc.split('\t'), ''),
        lat = chunks[3],
        long = chunks[4],
        name = chunks[16]

      Location.build({
        country: country,
        lat: lat,
        long: long,
        name: name
      })
        .save()
        .success(function(){
          console.log('success');
        })
        .error(function(err){
          if (err) throw err;
        });
    }

 }
```

I've tried using lodash's forEach method to iterate through the loops but both methods seem to be skipping over the Location.build()

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing actual code, but try using [fs.readFileSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) or, preferably, use [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) or async.auto for your loops, so that the outer loop actually finishes before the inner loop is executed.

Comment: I added the code I have. Would async.each be doing the same thing as _.forEach? Isn't async the problem here, not the solution?

Comment: I believe this should work with async.eachSeries. The thing that's hard to grasp about Node is that without using some form of callback or async function, Node progresses right through your outer and inner loops and on to the next item without waiting for the save to occur. I would recommend starting with 3 files, and adding console.log statements to see the control flow in action. It will surprise you.